# Double pendulum real time plot

Tags: python, tkinter, matplotlib, scipy

## Double Pendulum

I made a little application that embeds a `matplotlib` dynamic plot into `tkinter` that enables control through the `tkinter` GUI. Code is in [Github](https://github.com/bvermeulen/Double-Pendulum). It also uses `numpy` and `scipy` to solve the ordinary differential equations for a double pendulum.

To change the initial theta's just drag the bobs to another position...

[image: screen plot]

Would appreciate review for comments and improvements and I have one question: why does `highlightthickness` work for the `canvas_pendulum` (line 54)

```
cls.canvas_pendulum.get_tk_widget().configure(highlightthickness=1)
```

but not for canvas_graphs (line 72) ?

```
cls.canvas_graphs.get_tk_widget().configure(highlightthickness=1, bg='yellow')
```

## Code

Add the following packages to your environment

```
pip install numpy matplotlib scipy
```

```
import sys
import tkinter as tk
import time
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import patches as mpl_patches
from matplotlib import lines as mpl_lines
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg
from scipy.integrate import ode

TWOPI = 2*np.pi
PI = np.pi

FIG_SIZE_PENDULUM = (5, 5)
X_MIN, X_MAX = -10, 10
Y_MIN, Y_MAX = -10, 10
TICK_INTERVAL = 1.5

FIG_SIZE_GRAPHS = (5, 1)

update_label_interval_ms = 150
fps = 24
seconds_per_frame = 1 / fps
time_window_graphs = 20
update_graph_interval_s = 0.25


class MplMap():
    ''' set up map consisting of two figures: fig_pendulum and fig_graphs
        fig_pendulum: has one ax showing the pendulum movements
        fig_graphs: has two ax showing plots of theta1 and theta2
    '''
    @classmethod
    def settings(cls, root, fig_size_pendulum, fig_size_graphs):
        # set the plot outline, including axes going through the origin
        cls.root = root

        cls.fig_pendulum, cls.ax_pendulum = plt.subplots(figsize=fig_size_pendulum)
        cls.ax_pendulum.set_xlim(X_MIN, X_MAX)
        cls.ax_pendulum.set_ylim(Y_MIN, Y_MAX)
        cls.ax_pendulum.set_aspect(1)
        tick_range = np.arange(
            round(X_MIN + (10*abs(X_MIN) % TICK_INTERVAL*10)/10, 1),
            X_MAX + 0.1, step=TICK_INTERVAL)
        cls.ax_pendulum.set_xticks(tick_range)
        cls.ax_pendulum.set_yticks([])
        cls.ax_pendulum.tick_params(axis='x', which='major', labelsize=6)
        cls.ax_pendulum.spines['left'].set_color('none')
        cls.ax_pendulum.spines['right'].set_color('none')
        cls.ax_pendulum.spines['bottom'].set_position('zero')
        cls.ax_pendulum.spines['top'].set_color('none')
        cls.fig_pendulum.tight_layout()
        cls.canvas_pendulum = FigureCanvasTkAgg(cls.fig_pendulum, master=cls.root)
        cls.canvas_pendulum.get_tk_widget().configure(highlightthickness=1)

        cls.fig_graphs, (cls.ax_graph_1, cls.ax_graph_2) = plt.subplots(
            1, 2, figsize=fig_size_graphs)
        cls.ax_graph_1.set_ylim(-180, 180)
        cls.ax_graph_1.set_yticks([-180, -90, 0, 90, 180])
        cls.ax_graph_1.tick_params(axis='y', which='major', labelsize=6)
        cls.ax_graph_1.tick_params(axis='x', which='major', labelsize=6)
        cls.ax_graph_1.grid(True)

        cls.ax_graph_2.set_ylim(-190, 190)
        cls.ax_graph_2.set_yticks([-180, -90, 0, 90, 180])
        cls.ax_graph_2.tick_params(axis='y', which='major', labelsize=6)
        cls.ax_graph_2.tick_params(axis='x', which='major', labelsize=6)
        cls.ax_graph_2.grid(True)

        cls.fig_graphs.tight_layout()
        cls.canvas_graphs = FigureCanvasTkAgg(cls.fig_graphs, master=cls.root)
        cls.canvas_graphs.get_tk_widget().configure(highlightthickness=1, bg='yellow')

    @classmethod
    def get_cnvs_pendulum(cls):
        return cls.canvas_pendulum

    @classmethod
    def get_cnvs_graphs(cls):
        return cls.canvas_graphs


class DoublePendulum(MplMap):
    ''' class defining methods for Pendulum for positions and motions of a double
        pendulum
    '''
    def __init__(self, _a1, _a2):
        # Physical constants and initial settings
        self.g = 9.8
        self.damping1 = 0.0  # damping factor bob1
        self.damping2 = 0.0  # dampling factor bob2
        self.length_r1 = 5.0
        self.length_r2 = 2.5
        self.mass_bob1 = 5.0
        self.mass_bob2 = 2.5
        self.color_bob1 = 'green'
        self.color_bob2 = 'red'
        self.plotsize = 1.10 * (self.length_r1 + self.length_r2)

        # initial state
        if _a1 and _a2:
            self.theta1_initial = np.radians(_a1)
            self.theta2_initial = np.radians(_a2)
        else:
            self.theta1_initial = + 120 / 180 * np.pi
            self.theta2_initial = + 180 / 180 * np.pi
        self.theta1_dot_initial = 0
        self.theta2_dot_initial = 0
        self.theta1 = self.theta1_initial
        self.theta2 = self.theta2_initial
        self._time = 0

        _x1, _y1 = self.calc_xy(self.length_r1, self.theta1_initial)
        self.bob1 = mpl_patches.Circle((_x1, _y1), 0.2 + self.m1 * 0.02,
                                       fc=self.color_bob1, alpha=1, zorder=2)
        self.bob1.set_picker(0)
        self.ax_pendulum.add_patch(self.bob1)
        self.stick1 = mpl_lines.Line2D([0, _x1], [0, _y1], zorder=2)
        self.ax_pendulum.add_line(self.stick1)
        cv_bob1 = self.bob1.figure.canvas
        cv_bob1.mpl_connect('pick_event', self.on_pick)
        cv_bob1.mpl_connect('motion_notify_event', self.on_motion)
        cv_bob1.mpl_connect('button_release_event', self.on_release)

        _x2, _y2 = self.calc_xy(self.length_r2, self.theta2_initial)
        _x2 += _x1
        _y2 += _y1
        self.bob2 = mpl_patches.Circle((_x2, _y2), 0.2 + self.m2 * 0.02,
                                       fc=self.color_bob2, alpha=1, zorder=2)
        self.bob2.set_picker(0)
        self.ax_pendulum.add_patch(self.bob2)
        self.stick2 = mpl_lines.Line2D([_x1, _x2], [_y1, _y2], zorder=2)
        self.ax_pendulum.add_line(self.stick2)
        cv_bob2 = self.bob2.figure.canvas
        cv_bob2.mpl_connect('pick_event', self.on_pick)
        cv_bob2.mpl_connect('motion_notify_event', self.on_motion)
        cv_bob2.mpl_connect('button_release_event', self.on_release)

        self.x_traces = []
        self.y_traces = []
        self.trace_line, = self.ax_pendulum.plot(
            [0], [0], color='black', linewidth=0.2, zorder=1)

        self.current_object = None
        self.current_dragging = False
        self.break_the_loop = False

        self.theta_graphs = ThetaGraphs()
        self.blip()

    def switch_colors_of_bob(self):
        print('switch color')
        self.color_bob1, self.color_bob2 = self.color_bob2, self.color_bob1
        self.bob1.set_color(self.color_bob1)
        self.bob2.set_color(self.color_bob2)
        self.blip()

    def toggle_trace_visible(self):
        print(self.trace_line.get_visible())
        if self.trace_line.get_visible():
            self.trace_line.set_visible(False)
        else:
            self.trace_line.set_visible(True)
        self.blip()

    def clear_trace(self):
        self.x_traces = []
        self.y_traces = []
        self.trace_line.set_data([0], [0])
        self.blip()

    @property
    def gravity(self):
        return self.g

    @gravity.setter
    def gravity(self, value):
        self.g = value

    @property
    def m1(self):
        return self.mass_bob1

    @m1.setter
    def m1(self, value):
        self.mass_bob1 = value
        self.bob1.set_radius(0.2 + self.mass_bob1 * 0.02)
        self.blip()

    @property
    def m2(self):
        return self.mass_bob2

    @m2.setter
    def m2(self, value):
        self.mass_bob2 = value
        self.bob2.set_radius(0.2 + self.mass_bob2 * 0.02)
        self.blip()

    @property
    def l1(self):
        return self.length_r1

    @l1.setter
    def l1(self, value):
        self.length_r1 = value
        self.calc_positions()
        self.blip()

    @property
    def l2(self):
        return self.length_r2

    @l2.setter
    def l2(self, value):
        self.length_r2 = value
        self.calc_positions()
        self.blip()

    @property
    def k1(self):
        return self.damping1

    @k1.setter
    def k1(self, value):
        self.damping1 = value

    @property
    def k2(self):
        return self.damping2

    @k2.setter
    def k2(self, value):
        self.damping2 = value

    @property
    def angle1_initial(self):
        angle = self.theta1_initial
        return np.degrees(-PI + (angle - PI) % TWOPI)

    @property
    def angle2_initial(self):
        angle = self.theta2_initial
        return np.degrees(-PI + (angle - PI) % TWOPI)

    @property
    def angle1(self):
        angle = self.theta1
        return np.degrees(-PI + (angle - PI) % TWOPI)

    @property
    def angle2(self):
        angle = self.theta2
        return np.degrees(-PI + (angle - PI) % TWOPI)

    @property
    def time(self):
        return self._time

    def on_pick(self, event):
        if event.artist != self.bob1 and \
           event.artist != self.bob2:
            return

        self.current_dragging = True
        self.current_object = event.artist

    def on_motion(self, event):
        if not self.current_dragging:
            return
        if self.current_object == self.bob1:
            self.theta1 = self.calc_theta(event.xdata, event.ydata, self.theta1)
            self.theta1_initial = self.theta1

        elif self.current_object == self.bob2:
            _x1, _y1 = self.bob1.center
            self.theta2 = self.calc_theta(
                event.xdata - _x1, event.ydata - _y1, self.theta2)
            self.theta2_initial = self.theta2

        else:
            return

        self.calc_positions()
        self.blip()

    def on_release(self, _):
        self.current_object = None
        self.current_dragging = False

    def start_swing(self):
        self.break_the_loop = False
        self.theta1_initial = self.theta1
        self.theta2_initial = self.theta2
        self.y_traces = []
        self.x_traces = []
        self.plot_double_pendulum()

    def stop_swing(self):
        self.break_the_loop = True

    def calc_positions(self):
        _x1, _y1 = self.calc_xy(self.l1, self.theta1)
        self.bob1.center = (_x1, _y1)
        self.stick1.set_data([0, _x1], [0, _y1])

        _x2, _y2 = self.calc_xy(self.l2, self.theta2)
        _y2 += _y1
        _x2 += _x1
        self.bob2.center = (_x2, _y2)
        self.stick2.set_data([_x1, _x2], [_y1, _y2])

    def add_to_trace(self):
        _x2, _y2 = self.bob2.center
        self.x_traces.append(_x2)
        self.y_traces.append(_y2)
        self.trace_line.set_data(self.x_traces[:], self.y_traces[:])

    @staticmethod
    def calc_theta(x, y, theta):
        try:
            return np.arctan2(x, -y)
        except TypeError:
            return theta

    @staticmethod
    def calc_xy(length, theta):
        x = length * np.sin(theta)
        y = - length * np.cos(theta)
        return x, y

    def blip(self):
        self.fig_pendulum.canvas.draw()
        self.fig_pendulum.canvas.flush_events()

    def get_derivatives_double_pendulum(self, t, state):
        ''' definition of ordinary differential equation for a
            double pendulum. See for derivations at
            https://ir.canterbury.ac.nz/bitstream/handle/10092/12659/chen_2008_report.pdf
        '''
        t1, w1, t2, w2 = state
        dt = t1 - t2
        _sin_dt = np.sin(dt)
        _den1 = (self.m1 + self.m2 * _sin_dt * _sin_dt)

        _num1 = self.m2 * self.l1 * w1 * w1 * np.sin(2*dt)
        _num2 = 2 * self.m2 * self.l2 * w2 * w2 * _sin_dt
        _num3 = 2 * self.g * self.m2 * np.cos(t2) * _sin_dt + \
                2 * self.g * self.m1 * np.sin(t1)
        _num4 = 2 * (self.k1 * w1 - self.k2 * w2 * np.cos(dt))
        w1_dot = (_num1 + _num2 + _num3 + _num4)/ (-2 * self.l1 * _den1)

        _num1 = self.m2 * self.l2 * w2 * w2 * np.sin(2*dt)
        _num2 = 2 * (self.m1 + self.m2) * self.l1 * w1 * w1 * _sin_dt
        _num3 = 2 * self.g * (self.m1 + self.m2) * np.cos(t1) * _sin_dt
        _num4 = 2 * (self.k1 * w1 * np.cos(dt) - \
                    self.k2 * w2 * (self.m1 + self.m2)/ self.m2)
        w2_dot = (_num1 + _num2 + _num3 + _num4)/ (2 * self.l2 *_den1)

        state_differentiated = np.zeros(4)
        state_differentiated[0] = w1
        state_differentiated[1] = w1_dot
        state_differentiated[2] = w2
        state_differentiated[3] = w2_dot

        return state_differentiated

    def plot_double_pendulum(self):
        ''' methods to plot pendulum in matplotlib
        '''
        # note a frame per second (fps) > 24 the actual time
        # may not be able to keep up with model time

        def current_time():
            return time.time()

        def check_drift(_time, running_time):
            # check every 5 seconds
            if _time % 5 < seconds_per_frame:
                print(f'time (ms): {1000*_time:,.0f}, '
                      f'drift: {1000*(running_time - _time):,.0f}')

        self._time = 0
        dp_integrator = ode(self.get_derivatives_double_pendulum).set_integrator('vode')
        state = np.array([self.theta1, self.theta1_dot_initial,
                          self.theta2, self.theta2_dot_initial])
        dp_integrator.set_initial_value(state, self._time)

        self.add_to_trace()

        actual_start_time = current_time()
        while dp_integrator.successful() and not self.break_the_loop:

            self.theta1, _, self.theta2, _ = state

            self.calc_positions()
            self.add_to_trace()

            if self._time % update_graph_interval_s < seconds_per_frame:
                self.theta_graphs.plot_thetas(self._time, self.theta1, self.theta2)

            running_time = current_time() - actual_start_time
            check_drift(self._time, running_time)

            while running_time < self._time:
                running_time = current_time() - actual_start_time

            else:
                self.blip()

            state = dp_integrator.integrate(dp_integrator.t + seconds_per_frame)
            self._time += seconds_per_frame


class ThetaGraphs(MplMap):
    ''' Method to display the theta1 and theta2 graphs
    '''
    def __init__(self):
        self.time_window = time_window_graphs
        self.time_base = 0
        self.time_values = []
        self.angle1_values = []
        self.angle2_values = []
        self.theta1_graph, = self.ax_graph_1.plot(
            [0], [0], color='black', linewidth=0.5, zorder=2)
        self.theta2_graph, = self.ax_graph_2.plot(
            [0], [0], color='black', linewidth=0.5, zorder=2)
        self.ax_graph_1.set_xlim(
            self.time_base, self.time_base + self.time_window)
        self.ax_graph_2.set_xlim(
            self.time_base, self.time_base + self.time_window)

    def plot_thetas(self, _time, theta1, theta2):
        if _time % self.time_window < seconds_per_frame:

            # reset when time is zero
            if _time < seconds_per_frame:
                self.time_base = -self.time_window
                self.angle1_values = []
                self.angle2_values = []
                self.time_values = []

            self.time_base += self.time_window
            self.ax_graph_1.set_xlim(
                self.time_base, self.time_base + self.time_window)
            self.ax_graph_2.set_xlim(
                self.time_base, self.time_base + self.time_window)

        self.time_values.append(_time)

        self.angle1_values.append(np.degrees(-PI + (theta1 - PI) % TWOPI))
        self.theta1_graph.set_data(self.time_values, self.angle1_values)

        self.angle2_values.append(np.degrees(-PI + (theta2 - PI) % TWOPI))
        self.theta2_graph.set_data(self.time_values, self.angle2_values)

        self.fig_graphs.canvas.draw()
        self.fig_graphs.canvas.flush_events()


class TkHandler():
    ''' Methods to handle the tkinter GUI and links with matplotlib canvases and pendulum
        class. Methods:

        __init__:
            parameters:
            :root: tk root
            :cnvs_pendulum: maplotlib canvas showing the movement of the pendulum
            :cnvs_graphs: matplotlib canvas showing the graphs of theta1 and theta2
            :doublependulum: class handling the doublependulum status and positions

        create_slider_status_frame:
            Creates frame of the sliders and status values of initial theta1,
            initial theta2, time, theta1, theta2

            The slider values are connected to the pendulum class by the _set_value
            function that sets values for: gravity, mass1, mass2, length1, length2,
            damping1, damping2

        update_labels:
            Updates the status values. Update rate is set by: update_label_interval_ms

        create_button_frame:
            Creates frame with control buttons and links with button functions:
                _quit: quits the program

                The following button functions connect to the pendulum class to change
                status:
                _set_colors: swaps colors of the bobs
                _toggle_trace_visible: toggles trace on or off
                _clear_trace: clears the trace
                _start: starts the pendulum swing
                _stop: stops the pendulum swing

        create_grid:
            Creates the GUI grid
    '''
    def __init__(self, root, cnvs_pendulum, cnvs_graphs, doublependulum):
        self.root = root
        self.cnvs_pendulum = cnvs_pendulum
        self.cnvs_graphs = cnvs_graphs
        self.pendulum = doublependulum

        self.root.wm_title("Double Pendulum")
        self.create_slider_status_frame()
        self.create_button_frame()
        self.create_grid()
        self.update_labels()
        tk.mainloop()

    def create_slider_status_frame(self):
        self.sliders_status_frame = tk.Frame(self.root)
        sliders_frame = tk.Frame(self.sliders_status_frame)
        sliders = {'gravity': {'label':'Gravity   ', 'settings': [0, 30, 1]},        # 'settings': [min, max, resolution] # pylint: disable=C0301
                   'm1':      {'label':'Mass bob 1', 'settings': [1, 10, 0.1]},
                   'm2':      {'label':'Mass bob 2', 'settings': [1, 10, 0.1]},
                   'l1':      {'label':'Length r1 ', 'settings': [0.1, 10, 0.1]},
                   'l2':      {'label':'Length r2 ', 'settings': [0.1, 10, 0.1]},
                   'k1':      {'label':'Damping 1 ', 'settings': [0, 1, 0.1]},
                   'k2':      {'label':'Damping 2 ', 'settings': [0, 1, 0.1]},
                  }

        def create_slider(slider_key, slider_params):
            _min, _max, _resolution = slider_params['settings']

            slider_frame = tk.Frame(sliders_frame)
            label_slider = tk.Label(slider_frame, font=("TkFixedFont"),
                                    text=f'\n{slider_params["label"]:<11s}')
            slider = tk.Scale(slider_frame, from_=_min, to=_max, resolution=_resolution,
                              orient=tk.HORIZONTAL,
                              sliderlength=15,
                              length=150,
                              command=lambda value: self._set_value(value, slider_key))
            slider.set(getattr(self.pendulum, slider_key))
            label_slider.pack(side=tk.LEFT)
            slider.pack(side=tk.LEFT)
            slider_frame.pack()

        for key, slider_params in sliders.items():
            create_slider(key, slider_params)

        status_frame = tk.Frame(self.sliders_status_frame)
        self.label_status1 = tk.Label(status_frame, font=("TkFixedFont"),)
        self.label_status1.pack(anchor=tk.W)

        self.label_status2 = tk.Label(status_frame, font=("TkFixedFont"),)
        self.label_status2.pack(anchor=tk.W)

        self.label_status3 = tk.Label(status_frame, font=("TkFixedFont"),)
        self.label_status3.pack(anchor=tk.W)

        self.label_status4 = tk.Label(status_frame, font=("TkFixedFont"),)
        self.label_status4.pack(anchor=tk.W)

        self.label_status5 = tk.Label(status_frame, font=("TkFixedFont"),)
        self.label_status5.pack(anchor=tk.W)

        sliders_frame.pack(anchor=tk.NW)
        status_frame.pack(anchor=tk.W)

    def update_labels(self):
        self.label_status1.config(
            text=f'\ntheta1 initial: {self.pendulum.angle1_initial:+3.2f}')
        self.label_status2.config(
            text=f'theta2 initial: {self.pendulum.angle2_initial:+3.2f}')
        self.label_status3.config(
            text=f'time: {self.pendulum.time:+3.1f}')
        self.label_status4.config(
            text=f'theta1: {self.pendulum.angle1:+3.0f}')
        self.label_status5.config(
            text=f'theta2: {self.pendulum.angle2:+3.0f}')
        self.root.after(update_label_interval_ms, self.update_labels)

    def create_button_frame(self):
        self.buttons_frame = tk.Frame(self.root)

        tk.Button(
            self.buttons_frame, text='Quit', command=self._quit).pack(side=tk.LEFT)
        tk.Button(
            self.buttons_frame, text='Switch colors',
            command=lambda *args: self._set_colors(*args)).pack(side=tk.LEFT)
        tk.Button(
            self.buttons_frame, text='Trace on/ off',
            command=lambda *args: self._toggle_trace_visible(*args)).pack(side=tk.LEFT)
        tk.Button(
            self.buttons_frame, text='Clear trace',
            command=lambda *args: self._clear_trace(*args)).pack(side=tk.LEFT)
        tk.Button(
            self.buttons_frame, text='Start', command=self._start).pack(side=tk.LEFT)
        tk.Button(
            self.buttons_frame, text='Stop', command=self._stop).pack(side=tk.LEFT)

    def create_grid(self):
        tk.Grid.rowconfigure(self.root, 0, weight=1)
        tk.Grid.columnconfigure(self.root, 0, weight=1)
        self.sliders_status_frame.grid(
            row=0, column=0, sticky=tk.NW)
        self.cnvs_pendulum.get_tk_widget().grid(
            row=0, column=1, rowspan=1, columnspan=1, sticky=tk.W+tk.E+tk.N+tk.S)
        self.cnvs_graphs.get_tk_widget().grid(
            row=1, column=0, rowspan=1, columnspan=2, sticky=tk.W+tk.E+tk.N+tk.S)
        self.buttons_frame.grid(
            row=2, column=0, columnspan=2, sticky=tk.W)

    def _quit(self):
        self.pendulum.stop_swing()
        self.root.after(100, self.root.quit)
        self.root.after(100, self.root.destroy)

    def _set_colors(self):
        self.pendulum.switch_colors_of_bob()

    def _toggle_trace_visible(self):
        self.pendulum.toggle_trace_visible()

    def _clear_trace(self):
        self.pendulum.clear_trace()

    def _set_value(self, value, name):
        value = float(value)
        print(name, value)

        if name == 'gravity':
            self.pendulum.gravity = float(value)

        elif name == 'm1':
            self.pendulum.m1 = float(value)

        elif name == 'm2':
            self.pendulum.m2 = float(value)

        elif name == 'l1':
            self.pendulum.l1 = float(value)

        elif name == 'l2':
            self.pendulum.l2 = float(value)

        elif name == 'k1':
            self.pendulum.k1 = float(value)

        elif name == 'k2':
            self.pendulum.k2 = float(value)

        else:
            assert False, f'wrong key value given: {name}'

    def _start(self):
        self.pendulum.start_swing()

    def _stop(self):
        self.pendulum.stop_swing()


def main(_a1, _a2):
    root = tk.Tk()
    MplMap.settings(root, FIG_SIZE_PENDULUM, FIG_SIZE_GRAPHS)
    TkHandler(root, MplMap.get_cnvs_pendulum(),
              MplMap.get_cnvs_graphs(), DoublePendulum(_a1, _a2))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main_arguments = sys.argv
    angle1 = None
    angle2 = None

    if len(main_arguments) == 3:
        try:
            angle1 = float(main_arguments[1])
            angle2 = float(main_arguments[2])
        except ValueError:
            print('invalid arguments, refer to defaults ..')

    main(angle1, angle2)
```